# Best Practice to Pause in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, timeout

What is the best way to pause in JavaScript. I have attempted to use the setTimeout() function before, but I really got confused on how it works.

Comment: pausing what? what are trying to accomplish?

Comment: and possible duplicate of [Javascript sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var pauseTime = 1000; //this is in milliseconds
setTimeout(runThisFunction,pauseTime);

function runThisFunction(){
 alert("i waited a second to run!");
}
```

#### it works by waiting x milliseconds then calls the function you pass .. in this case the function name is runThisFunction

Comment: If you replace the alert with a print statement, it will NOT guarantee that the function will run for x milliseconds.